# Stop jinja from converting string to url encoding?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm currently using some Jinja2 templating on my flask app to pull up images on an html page using image paths from a simple sqlite request. I.e. the process is as follows:

**1. Retrieve image path from SQLite**
In SQLite its simply a text field, i.e.:

`imagePath text`

For example, this would be something like "post1.png"

**2. Format a render template for the html page**
Using url_for, create an image element with the given image path, i.e.:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/images/blog/{{ imagePath }}') }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

So, I would expect to see something like:

`<img src="assets/images/blog/post1.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

But, instead I'm getting some weird url encoding when the page gets rendered, i.e.:

`<img src="/static/assets/images/blog/%7B%7B%20post%5B7%5D%20%7D%7D" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

Am I doing something wrong in the templating process? Or is there something I can do to remove all of those hex characters that are generated? I tried passing in a string filter but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: try printing what `imagePath` really is

Comment: Your url encoding translates to `{{ post[7] }}`. That's not a great choice for a image filename.

Comment: You cannot nest the curly braces {{ }} so Jinja is escaping them as part of the URL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845452/3357118 discusses an almost identical use case with url_for()

Answer (score 4):

[Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping) says:

> When automatic escaping is enabled, everything is escaped by default except for values explicitly marked as safe. Variables and expressions can be marked as safe either in:
>   - the context dictionary by the application with MarkupSafe.Markup, or
>   - the template, with the `|safe` filter

So, you can try to use `safe` filter ( http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe ):

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/images/blog/' ~ imagePath ) | safe }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

or follow other suggestions from Jinja2 template docs.