# Django: How to add html tag from string to the html template

Tags: python, html, json, django

Details:
Client framwork: Django

Web server: Python + Flask

I have an HTML page which rendered with a data array.
Each item in the array contains some fields. And one of the fields is a json object.

In order to improve the visibility of the json i've converted the json obj to html table.

Currently it's does't work.
The results (on the browser) looks like that:

```
PasswordPolicy <table border="1"><tr><th>MinimumPasswordLength</th><td>16</td></tr><tr><th>RequireSymbols</th><td>True</td></tr><tr><th>Re
```

[image: image1]

Flask code:

```
@app.route("/PasswordPolicy", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def get_password_policy():
    get_table_content = list(db_object.get_password_policy())
    search_event = request.args.get('searchquery')
    at_type = request.args.get('audittype')
        print("**************")
        for e in get_table_content:
            print("Before:")
            print(e['PasswordPolicy'])
            e['PasswordPolicy'] = json2html.convert(json = e['PasswordPolicy'])
            print("After:")
            print(e['PasswordPolicy'])

        print("get_table_content:")
        print(get_table_content[0])
        print("**************")
        return render_template(
            'soc2/password_policy.html',
            get_list=get_table_content
        )
```

Html content:

```
                        <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="headings">
                            <th class="column-title">BusinessUnit </th>
                            <th class="column-title">ControllerNumber </th>
                            <th class="column-title">PasswordPolicy </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        {% for elements in get_list %}
                        <tr class="even pointer">
                            <td>
                                {{ elements["BusinessUnit"] }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ elements["ControllerNumber"] }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ elements["PasswordPolicy"] }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The question is how to tell to the browser to parse the table as html instead of simple string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171092/4151233

Answer (score 2):

You can use `safe` like so: `{{ your_html_string | safe }}`