# Python Flask template nested {{}}

Tags: python, templates, ninja

How do I dynamically add the value of 'engine' in this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{
      url_for('static', filename='js/{{engine}}.js') }}"></script>
```

'engine' is not translated properly.

Comment: [nested-print-statements-in-jinja-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843661/nested-print-statements-in-jinja-template) may help

Comment: `filename='js/' + engine + '.js'`

Comment: This works. Much easier than I thought.